# Search documents have at least one word in a list in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to search documents with 1) some phrases that must exist in one of three fields 2) and a list words in which at least one of them occurs in one of the fields, such as ['supply', 'procure', 'purchase'].

Below is the current ES query I use which meets the first requirement. However, how should I add the word list in this query?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ 
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "ford",
                        "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "description",
                            "news_content"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "lone star",
                        "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "description",
                            "news_content"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your mapping and one document as example

Comment: Hi, Did you get a chance to look at my answer? please let me know if you hv further quesytions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just add operator `OR` in your query, which would solve your second use case of `list words in which at least one of them occurs in one of the fields,`

Let me show if you by an example:

**Index def**

```
{
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" :{
            "title" :{
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "description":{
                "type" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "title" : "foo",
    "description": "opster"
}
{
    "title" : "bar",
    "description": "stackoverflow"
}
{
    "title" : "baz",
    "description": "nodesc"
}
```

**Search query, notice I am searching for `foo amit`, list of words so atleast one of them should match in any of 2 fields**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "foo amit",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "description"
                    ],
                    "operator":   "or" --> notice operator OR
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "white",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.9808291,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo",  --> notice this match as `foo` is present and we used opertor OR in query.
                    "description": "opster"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: How can I also incorporate the first requirement?